# HTML - Prevent overflow?

Tags: html, css

My site has a footer with content,
but if you look on a bigger screen, or zoom out,
it will flow out of the div.

### [LIVE DEMO](http://artotek.fi/)

### Code

---

```
#yht { //Footer container
width: 100%;
min-height: 20px;
max-height: 30px;
vertical-align: middle;
background: black;
text-align:center;
opacity: 0.7;
max-height: auto;
height: auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

#main:hover #yht span {
opacity: 1;
}

#yht span {
text-align:center;
position: relative;
display: block;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
padding: 5px;
}

#yht2 { //Text ul
display: block;
height: auto;
max-height: auto;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
}

#yht2 ul li {
font-size: 50px;
color: magenta;
overflow: hidden;
display: block;
margin-top: auto;
margin-bottom: auto;
}
```

Comment: As your site may change over time, could you provide a jsfiddle - this will allow others who may have the same problem as you in the future to refer to the jsfiddle which will not be changed (a lot, as a website may be).

Comment: Cannot reproduce issue in Chrome 32

Answer (score 1):

Remove `max-height: 30px;` on the ID `#yht`.